# How can we track cookies and pages visited with user - Firefox / Sqlite

Tags: firefox, sqlite, cookies

We have a problem with our SAAS site.  We sometimes have users kicked out because our authentication cookie is not there (or possibly corrupted).  This happens rarely enough that it is hard to find, but often enough that I want to know why.

I want to install a monitor / sniffer for one of our support engineers. They get the problem every once and a while and can stop and call when it happens.

I am looking for something that will log page visits (with timestamp) and cookie changes (create/mod/delete).

Does anyone have a tool that will do this type of logging for FireFox?  Maybe a Sqlite tool that will work for Firefox (which I think takes exclusive on the Sqlite db file).

Comment: So this is something you want to deploy to clients?

Comment: Not at all.  Looking to debug this on one of our machines (one of our support engineers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) can help you. Open the Tamper Data window. Do the requests. Right click -> Export as XML. You can view the cookies by double clicking on the Cookie header.